# Why does my jQuery code POST return a query string in my URL?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

So I've followed some guides online and made a simple jQuery POST.

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function () {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/OhSnip/api/users/",
        dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }

    })
});
```

However, whenever I click the login button, the page returns a query string and completely ignores the success function, writing nothing on the console.

```
http://localhost:8080/OhSnip/?username=username&password=password.
```

Why does this happen?

I've tried many different formats and whatnot, but I have been unable to solve this issue by myself so far.

Tutorials on youtube aren't really helping either.

[image: the backend works fine]

The backend works fine, as you can see from the picture above, but here's the code anyway

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User logIn(
        @FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("password") String password) {

    UserManager um = UserManager.getInstance();

    return um.logIn(username, password);
}
```

Anyway, thanks.

EDIT: Form html code.

```
<form id="logIn" action="">
     <div class='form-group'>
          <label for='username' class='sr-onl'>Username</label>
          <input id='username' type='username' required='' placeholder='Username' class='form-control' name='username'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
          <label for='password' class='sr-onl'>Password</label>
          <input id='password' type='password' required='' placeholder='Password' class='form-control' name='password'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
         <button id="btnLogin" class='btn btn-block'>Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are there different ports at the URL's at Question?

Comment: the tomcat server was using port8080 so I was forced to change it to 8081.
I've changed back since then but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide your html code as well? If #btnLogin is inside a form, and that form doesn't have e.preventDefault() bound to the submit function plus method=post in the <form> tag, the it will submit as a GET and bypass the AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using AJAX, the URL in the script overrides any URL that's in the form action attribute, but you can use

`<form id="logIn" action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST">`

You do need the e.preventDefault() in the button function and the POST method on the form as you do in your second example. Otherwise the default behaviour of a button within an HTML form is to submit the form as a regular GET request, in which form values are attached to the URL as a query string. The e.preventDefault() is necessary to tell the form to follow the script instead of submitting the usual way and the method="POST" tells the form it's a POST request not GET.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was an HTML form problem as Jwebb suggested.

I added the action and the method parameters to the form.

```
<form id="logIn" action="api/users" method="POST">
      <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='username' class='sr-onl'>Username</label>
            <input id='username' type='username' required='' placeholder='Username' class='form-control' name='username'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='password' class='sr-onl'>Password</label>
            input id='password' type='password' required='' placeholder='Password' class='form-control' name='password'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-group'>
            <button id="btnLogin" class='btn btn-block'>Login</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Aswell as the event.preventDefault() function to the submit button

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/OhSnip/api/users/",
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
        },
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    }) 
});
```